# flex-basis: auto doesn't work in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have 3 divs with different width that I want to shrink to container using flexbox.

Made a fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/easyNick/1m8ude39/14/

CSS looks like this:

```
.child {
 order: 0;
 flex-grow: 0;
 flex-shrink: 1;
 flex-basis: auto;
 min-height: auto;
 min-width: auto;
 align-self: auto;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 padding: 0 0.25rem;
}
```

Works great in Chrome ets.

[image]

But IE 11 sees flex-basis as width and last div doesn't even fit to container:

```
.child {
 order: 0;
 flex-grow: 0;
 flex-shrink: 1;
 width: auto;
 min-height: auto;
 min-width: auto;
 align-self: auto;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 padding: 0 0.25rem;
}
```

[image]

I've found some advices to set flex-basis to some percentage number. But 100% doesn't make what I need.

[image]

Setting particular values makes layout not flexible.

Any ideas of what may help?

Comment: could you please paste some fiddle as I can reproduce the problem

Comment: made a fiddle a fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/easyNick/1m8ude39/14/

Comment: I think the issue is with the input, try playing around with the width of the input or the display property. I don't have IE11 so I cannot test but give it a shot

Comment: This is strange, first IE11 couldn't open jsfiddle.net so I copied your code to jsbin. And there everything was working [here](http://jsbin.com/vadubavoyi/1/edit?html,css,output) you can check it out. I have just removed some of your css that should be by default with the same values.

Comment: Yeah, [jsFiddle no longer supports IE](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/1257). Codepen also fails in IE. Use JSBin.com instead. That said, your code seems to work fine in IE with JSBin.

Answer (score 2):

`Flex-basis`  [wont work on the IE11](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#7-flex-basis-doesnt-account-for-box-sizingborder-box).

> But you can target `flex-basis` property using this CSS rule. Try this one

```
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .IE-FlexAuto {
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

Comment: Should I somehow adjust this css selectors`_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .IE-FlexAuto`?

Comment: @nick722, the class at the end can be changed to any selector you like.